# jqplot problem with highlighter

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I'm using the jQuery plugins provided by jqplot for charting.
When I use seriesDefaults : { fill : true }, the highlighter (tooltip) stops working.

Here is the code I'm using.

```
var line1=[['23-May-08', 578.55], ['20-Jun-08', 566.5], ['25-Jul-08', 480.88], ['22-Aug-08', 509.84],
    ['26-Sep-08', 454.13], ['24-Oct-08', 379.75], ['21-Nov-08', 303], ['26-Dec-08', 308.56],
    ['23-Jan-09', 299.14], ['20-Feb-09', 346.51], ['20-Mar-09', 325.99], ['24-Apr-09', 386.15]];

var plot = $.jqplot('chartarea', [line1],
                   {
                    seriesDefaults : { fill : true },
                    title          : "Area chart with tooltip",
                    axes           : {
                                      xaxis : { renderer : $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer },
                                      yaxis : { tickOptions : { formatString : '$%.2f'} }
                                     },
                    highlighter    : { show : true, sizeAdjust : 7.5},
                    cursor         : { show : false } 
                   });
```

Is there any way to get the highlighter working in fill : true case.

Thanks..

Comment: I see this error in firebug "s.gridData[neighbor.pointIndex] is undefined". Looks like it's a bug in jqplot

Comment: Did someone resolve this issue, I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hack intro the jqplot js file to make this work. I managed to get this to work, but the fill area under the line won't change its transparency on hover any more.

You can look in the JS file for `switch (s.renderer.constructor) {` and in the following case `case $.jqplot.LineRenderer:` comment the code for the `if (s.fill) {` and leave just the code for the else.

You'll get an error somewhere in `$.jqplot.ShapeRenderer.prototype.draw = function(ctx, points, options) {` because points is not defined, but you can use an if here to check if points is set.

This may not be the best solution, but we really needed the tooltips for a filled line, and this was, for now, the best option.

Comment: Just so anyone else looking for a solution to this problem (I ran in to it too, on both the newest stable release as well as the most recent alpha), there's an issue open on the project page about this exact problem: https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/issue/261/highlighter-doesnt-work-when-using-fill